# Set Windows Explorer's View Default Layout

Tags: windows

I want to set the "**Detailed**" layout as default Windows Explorer's View to *all folders*. But I can't find any setting regarding this. Can someone point me to the right options/settings? [Screenshot of View settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05NKA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 10 from Windows Explorer you can click on the View tab -> options -> view

Under the folder views section you can hit apply to folders.

(before doing that make sure to change the view to details)

If you do that from your C:\ or the drive of your choice I think that will apply to the changes to all the sub folders within C drive.

Thanks 
A